# Android  Google Analytics (R.id) Renaming Buttons

Tags: android, button, renaming

```
Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);

Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
```

Hallo
I have searched all over but I don't get it. Should I change the "NewEventButton" to something like "button01".
The problem is that if I change it, the button it stops working, normal the button when is clicked it opens the phone browser and navigate to a website.

The same happens with the "NewPageButton", eclipse asking to be changed also to "button01" for example.

If I leave them as it is, I have errors like "cannot be resolver or is not a field"

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Thats the main xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/aevbackground"
android:id="@+id/main"
    >

    <Button android:text="Other" android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="33dp" 
android:onClick="myonclick1" android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"></Button>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello1"
    />

<Button android:text="Home" android:id="@+id/button01" android:layout_width="230dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser1"></Button>
<Button android:text="Forum" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="210dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser2"></Button>
<Button android:text="FOC" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="190dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser3"></Button>
<Button android:text="ON TFC" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="170dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser4"></Button>
<Button android:text="At Facebook" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser5"></Button>
<Button android:text="At Twitter" android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_width="130dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser6"></Button>
<Button android:text="At Google+" android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_width="110dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="openBrowser7"></Button>     
<Button android:text="@string/linkEmail" android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="34dp" 
android:onClick="linkEmailClicked"></Button>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thats the main java file with Google analytics

```
package com.av0001;


import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
     // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
        tracker.startNewSession("UA-25624837-1", this);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.trackEvent(
                "Clicks",  // Category
                "Button",  // Action
                "clicked", // Label
                77);       // Value
          }
        });

        Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp" and
            // scope of session-level.
            tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Navigation Type", "Button click", 2);
            // Track a page view. This is probably the best way to track which parts of your application
            // are being used.
            // E.g.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/help"); to track someone looking at the help screen.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/level2"); to track someone reaching level 2 in a game.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/uploadScreen"); to track someone using an upload screen.
            tracker.trackPageView("/mainspalsh");
            tracker.trackPageView("/main");
            tracker.trackPageView("/main2");
            tracker.trackPageView("/main3");

          }
        });

        Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
          }
        });

        Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was started with a dispatch
            // interval.
            tracker.dispatch();
          }
        });
      }
        public void openBrowser1(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
           startActivity(i);
        }
        public void openBrowser2(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public void openBrowser3(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public void openBrowser4(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i); 
        }
        public void openBrowser5(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i);    
        }
        public void openBrowser6(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public void openBrowser7(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(""));
            startActivity(i);
        } 
        public void linkEmailClicked(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] tos = {getString(R.string.emailAddress)};
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos);
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.emailSubject));
            it.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(it);
        }
        public void myonclick1(View view) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,Main2.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Thank you for using xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx application, enjoy browsing :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();  
        }
            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                // The activity is about to become visible.
            }
            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
            }
            @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
            }
            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                // The activity is about to be destroyed.
             // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
                tracker.stopSession();
            }
        }
```

Comment: show your activity's whole code.

Comment: clean your code may be? Project->clean

Comment: You should use a meaningful title for your question

Comment: And show your XML layout too.

Comment: Hi, clean has not worked. How can I post the xml now? Thanks

Comment: Exactly but if I define the same button, then the button is not working anymore.

Comment: must sure you use the same id in xml file and your activity for access the buttons.

Comment: just click on the edit button and say put something like this on the end Update: this is my layout.xml file and post that in there

Comment: Done it, you can see the update, thanks.

Comment: Also changed the post title. Thanks

Comment: Oh dear God, I cannot solve this !!!!

Comment: @aromero You must take the minus back I think sir.

Comment: You know you have 4 listeners registered to the same button r.id.button01...that maybe causing some issues.

Comment: Hallo, yes I know that but as I said below, I am not sure what to do, should I change the other listeners to some other buttons, excuse me but I am not so familiar with this and so far I read about it I don't find some clear instructions. I will try this know. Thank you

Comment: Just try it, I have changed the button accordingly till button4 which is the "ON TFC", know neither of the first 4 button are working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that you are renaming it but not changing the XML layout id name and hence the R.java does not have the new name.  If you are changing the XML too, then you are not re-compiling the project.  Make sure to have the auto-compile selected in your Eclipse environment.  Go to Project -> Build Automatically and make sure it has a check mark next to it.

----Alternate Suggestions ----
What version of eclipse are you using and ADB...you might have to upgrade to the latest and reinstal ADB....  I had something similar with compilation errors and only upgrading and re-install worked.  your code compiles fine for me. Not sure how your going to reach some of these methods and you do have 4 listeners listening to the same button R.id.button01.  Here is your code running in my eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand, as I asked, should I eave this as it is or replace with "button01". Where is this "auto-compile" setting, I cannot find it, thanks.

Comment: You can pretty much name whatever you want for your buttons id name...just have to make sure that you change the id="+id/yourname" in your layout.xml code.  And then change any reference to it.

Comment: Have found the setting, was already like this. Did see it at your previous post. Thanks

Comment: Ok, first, I have add the "android:id="@+id/main" at main.xml which should be fine with the connection with the java file, can you please check it, I have update the codes above, xml and java too.Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have again recheck the button id for all of them and also check the additions at R.java, which seems to be ok. But again when I click at butto01, its like the button to be dead. If i switch back this "Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);" to "Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);" then the button is working again as it should be. thanks

Comment: Good day, I have try so many thinks having no positive result.Can you please confirm that this "Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);" should be changed to something like this "Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);" at this case as example. I don't know what else to do!!!Thanks

Comment: My installation is fresh, I'll leave this for last solution. Thanks

Comment: Have you try to reproduce my problem by adding links at "Uri.parse(""));" ? Thanks

Comment: Ok, that thing is not working at all, I had to remove the events tracking in order to have achieve tracking, thats not good, I will find the solution at future maybe! The tutorial from Android development are not even good I have to say. Thats a pity!

Comment: Just a quick question what version of the SDK are you using and what version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.0 Build id: I20110613-1736 and for ANDROID installer_r12-windows.

Comment: Yes thats strange, anyway I have rebuild the application with webviews and I don't need this option anymore but if we can solve the issue for future intents that will be good! Thanks for support